# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' ERROR in Flask SqlAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Building a Flask application i am getting this error
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`
when trying to pass a value selected by user from SelectField from Forms

```
class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])
    surname = StringField('Surname', validators=[Length(min=2, max=80)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    picture = FileField('Update Profile Picture', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'svg'])])
    province = SelectField(u'Select Province', choices=[('Choose', '--') ,('EC', 'Eastern Cape'), ('FS', 'Free State'), ('GP', 'Gauteng')])
    #province = SelectField(u'Select Province', choices=PROVINCES, coerce=str)
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
```

and model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    surname = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.svg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    #province = db.Column(db.String(180))
    province = db.relationship('Moter', backref='user', uselist=False)

class Moter(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement = True)
    short_intro = db.Column(db.Text(100))
    about_me = db.Column(db.Text(260))
    date_joined = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    province = db.Column(db.String(180), nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

and my route

```
@app.route('/update_profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update_profile():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.picture.data:
            picture_file = save_picture(form.picture.data)
            current_user.image_file = picture_file
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        current_user.name = form.name.data
        current_user.surname = form.surname.data
        current_user.province = form.province.data #dict(PROVINCES).get(form.province.data)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been updated', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.name.data = current_user.name
        form.surname.data = current_user.surname
        form.email.data = current_user.email
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
    return render_template('update_profile.html', title='Update Profile', image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

Could someone shed some light what i am doing wrong - i looked at other posts relating to this but i don't quite get how to update my SelectField to pass relevant data

Comment: You're setting the relationship to a string - that won't work. It'll have to be set to an actual ORM object. Usually you'd have a `province_id` that you could set directly to the id instead.

Comment: thanks for the update @MatsLindh, if i understood correctly i should add `province_id` to the child table Moter and have a province relationship on a parent table User eg.
in Moter:

`province = db.Column(db.String(180), nullable=True)`
`province_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))`
in User:
`province = db.relationship('Moter', backref='user', uselist=False)`

Comment: No, that would put the relationship the wrong way - i.e. a province could only be defined for a single user. On user: `province_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('moter.id')), province = db.relationship('Moter', backref='users', uselist=False)`

Comment: hmm then i must have something else wrong as i am getting the same error when i add that, anywhere else i should look at, perhaps templates or?